# Unity3D Unable to list target platforms error

Tags: android, ubuntu, unity-game-engine, java-8

I am using Unity3D editor beta for linux in my ubuntu 14.04 desktop.

whenever I tried to build unity application for android, I got the error
like this

---

```
 Error building Player: CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to list target platforms. Please make sure the android sdk path is correct. See the Console for more details. 
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java -Xmx2048M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="/home/yeol/AndroidSDK/tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "/opt/Unity/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Tools/sdktools.jar" -

stderr[
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at SDKMain.main(SDKMain.java:129)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.android.sdklib.ISystemImage.getTag()Lcom/android/sdklib/repository/descriptors/IdDisplay;
    at com.android.sdklib.SystemImage.compareTo(SystemImage.java:278)
    at com.android.sdklib.SystemImage.compareTo(SystemImage.java:37)
    at java.util.TreeMap.compare(TreeMap.java:1294)
    at java.util.TreeMap.put(TreeMap.java:538)
    at java.util.TreeSet.add(TreeSet.java:255)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.local.LocalPlatformPkgInfo.getPlatformSystemImages(LocalPlatformPkgInfo.java:362)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.local.LocalPlatformPkgInfo.createAndroidTarget(LocalPlatformPkgInfo.java:248)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.local.LocalPlatformPkgInfo.getAndroidTarget(LocalPlatformPkgInfo.java:104)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.local.LocalSdk.getTargets(LocalSdk.java:712)
    at com.android.sdklib.SdkManager.getTargets(SdkManager.java:181)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.displayTargetList(Main.java:968)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.doAction(Main.java:318)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.run(Main.java:151)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.main(Main.java:117)
    ... 5 more
 ]
```

---

I got confused because It did not show the error about few days ago when I tried to build same application.

But the error has showed up since I updated my packages in ubuntu.

So I tried to reinstall all of SDK and check the SDK path to resolve the problem.
But It is not resolved.

[image]

my SDK tools version is rev 25.2.4

sdk-platform tools are 25.0.2

android-sdk-build-tools are 25.0.2 , 25.0.1, etc

unity version is 5.5.0xf3

jdk version is 8u111

what should I check ?

please let me know if you know how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Got the same issue, answer is given in the following thread.....

[not finding android sdk (Unity)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42538433/not-finding-android-sdk-unity#)

mine solved perfectly, hope this helps.. also don't forget to copy zip align from one of the build tools(Android/sdk/buildtools) to the tools(Android/sdk/tools) folder, though newer versions might work without it, but still...!!