# Android Studio - SDK Manager

Tags: android, android-studio, command

When I type 'android' at my command prompt I have the following message 'The "android" command is no longer available. For manual SDK and AVD management, please use Android Studio. For command-line tools, use tools\bin\sdkmanager.bat and tools\bin\avdmanager.bat'.

What do I do?

Comment: Forgive me, I'm new to application development, I'm learning slowly.

Comment: check this link ..https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/2583

Comment: The `sdkmanager` app is not at all the same as the old `android` app; it's geared towards config scripts &c, and the output is very terse and hard to read.

It's not a substitute for `android`, if you are (say) using IntelliJ, not Android Studio.

The strange thing, here, is that the IntelliJ "Android Support" enables a Tools / Android / SDK Manager window that looks just like the old `android` app. It would appear the old code is still there, perhaps in a .jar file.

Does anyone know how to activate it?

Comment: You can downgrade your tools - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42538433/not-finding-android-sdk-unity#

Answer (score 6):

The standalone GUI based SDK manager (and AVD manager) is now gone!

You either have to use the standalone command at `<SDK_ROOT>\tools\bin\sdkmanager` or
the inbuilt GUI SDK manager within the `Android Studio` found at: `Tools`>`Android` > `SDK Manager`

Comment: I see an error: **Your android sdk is missing, out of date or corrupted**

Answer (score 4):

Not sure what has caused this but there is a workaround you just need to download and replace the tools folder in your Android SDK with an earlier version and it will work again.

Follow these steps:

1. Click the link below for your OS and download a new Android SDK tools folder:

   - (Mac) https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.3-macosx.zip
   - (Windows) https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.3-windows.zip
2. Goto your Android SDK folder (on Mac its: /Users/username/Library/Android/sdk) then find the folder named "tools" and delete it
3. Unzip and copy the tools folder you downloaded from the link to your Android SDK folder

That's it.. You should now be able to run the android command from the terminal again

Answer (score 0):

I had to navigate to and run the following

```
cd /Users/<username>/Library/Android/sdk
tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses
```