# android.bat not opening Android SDK manager

Tags: java, android, android-sdk-tools, java-6

Yes, this question has been asked before. But the solutions on the internet are not working so that's why I am asking it here. I'm guessing the solutions aren't working because I am using newer versions but I'm not sure.

**Bit of Background:** So I am making a small game in Unity. I have to test it on Android so I can check if there are any problems or not. So I check around the internet on how I may be able to do that. Turns out, I need to change the build settings to android and I also need JDK installed on my computer along with Android SDK Manager so I download them both. I did not install the Android Studio but just the Command Line Tools because many tutorials say that I do not actually need the whole Android Studio because I'm gonna be making the app in Unity not in Android Studio. So I do that. I install JDK and Extract the command line tools.

I think the JDK installed fine because after installing JDK, I opened Internet Explorer (No, I don't use IE, I use Chrome but I opened it just for fun). And a little notification showed up at the bottom which basically said that I could now run Java on the browser so that's why I don't think there are any problems with the JDK installation.

**Problem:** I extracted Command Line tools of Android Studio and found that there was only a tools/ folder in it. I opened it and clicked on android.bat but the Android SDK manager doesn't work. A CMD screen just flashes for a moment but then nothing happens.

**Solution I have Tried:**

Change set java_exe to:

```
set java_exe="C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe"
```

and delete the line:

```
call libjava_find.bat
```

But I can't find set java_exe code anywhere in the file. The file doesn't have it. How am I supposed to change it?

Comment: Android SDK manager is now UI-less ... the only UI for it is now in AS

Comment: Ah. I was getting a little frustrated but that's good to know. I solved the problem btw.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I figured it out but I was still unable to pinpoint the problem. Here is what I did:

1. Installed a fresh copy of Windows 10. Note: It is highly unlikely that this will solve the problem. But where I live, it is very common to just install a fresh copy of windows whenever you get a problem. I really don't think you need to do this.
2. Follow all the instructions from: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yLFBu-VlBIw
3. If you get the following error:
   Error building Player: CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to list target platforms. Then use this fix: [not finding android sdk (Unity)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42538433/not-finding-android-sdk-unity#)

These steps solved the problem for me and I was able to run it properly.