# Unity failed to build for android - CommandInvokationFailure

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

Unity seems to not be able to build android app, iOS build is working properly

I have this error :

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to build apk.
    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.4.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Xmx2048M -
    Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="/Users/me/Library/Android/sdk/tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "/Applications/Unity/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Tools/sdktools.jar" -

    stderr[
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at SDKMain.main(SDKMain.java:130)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/misc/BASE64Encoder
    at com.android.sdklib.internal.build.SignedJarBuilder.<init>(SignedJarBuilder.java:177)
    at com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder.init(ApkBuilder.java:446)
    at com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder.<init>(ApkBuilder.java:422)
    at com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder.<init>(ApkBuilder.java:362)
    at UnityApkBuilder.<init>(UnityApkBuilder.java:214)
    at UnityApkBuilder.main(UnityApkBuilder.java:34)
    ... 5 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.misc.BASE64Encoder
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:466)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:563)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
    ... 11 more
    ]
    stdout[

    ]
    exit code: 1
    UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommandInternal (System.String javaExe, System.String sdkToolsDir, System.String[] sdkToolCommand, Int32 memoryMB, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommandSafe (System.String javaExe, System.String sdkToolsDir, System.String[] sdkToolCommand, Int32 memoryMB, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

Tried everything already referenced on StackOverflow like replacing sdk tools by version 25, and I have installed JDK 9, same thing was happening with JDK 1.8

I'm running on Unity 2017.3.1f1

Worth noticed that I have the same error when I try to build an empty project so it's not related to strange code or whatever.

Comment: 1.Can you build empty project for Android? 2.Are you suing plugins like Google play.....

Comment: I don't think so I didn't change anything in player setting except package name

Comment: Yes same problem on empty project

Comment: Closed similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48873259) few minutes ago. Please try the answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42538433) question. It seems similar but not sure if the-same. Let me know if that solves your problem

Comment: Yes! Good configuration is as said in comments sdk 26 tools 25.3 jdk 1.8.0